# zero width negative look ahead assertion perl

Tags: regex, perl

I have following text save in a file and trying to do regex

```
line1 brown fox
line2 black owl
line3 red dear
```

When i am trying to run following perl command,

```
perl -ne 'print if /(line.*)(?!.*fox)/' text.txt
```

it is printing all three lines (instead of printing the line2 and line3).
How is this matching first line? i get expected results if i use following perl statement

```
perl -ne 'print if /(line)(?!.*fox)/' text.txt
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

All three strings successfully match because the `.*` preceding the lookahead is greedily matching every single character and gobbled up the whole string. The engine will then advance attempting to assert that what follows in the string is not "foo"; backtracking to `.*` inside of the lookahead and greedily repeating until it asserts at the end of the string position.

Place the lookahead at the beginning of the string to assert that at the current position and what follows is not "fox". If the lookahead succeeds, the engine will continue to match.

```
perl -ne 'print if /^(?!.*fox).*/' text.txt
```

The above will look ahead to see if there is not any character (*except newline*) or "fox". If successful then match any character (*except newline*) in other words the whole string.

Comment: Ok if line*. is consuming the entire string before lookahead even gets tried, then why the following statement returns correct result  perl -ne 'print if /(line.*)(?=.*fox)/' text.txt....when this statement i am only getting line1.

Comment: Because the regex engine will find a way to match if there is one. Your original attempt rules out one possible match but the engine just finds another. By contrast, this solution finds the match in the negative lookahead if there is one.

Comment: @hwnd: (line.*) matching the all three lines and treat every line as one whole string makes sense but if i replace negative lookahead with positive than it doesn't give expected result....so if i use following script                        perl -ne 'print if /(line.*)(?!.*fox)/; print "$1\n"' test3.txt
line1 brown fox
line1 brown fox
line2 black owl
line2 black owl
line3 red dear
line3 red dear                                                                                              then printing the first group ($1) shows that entire line is matched by (line.*) as seen in above outputs.

Comment: @hwnd: but if i use positive lookahead in same script, printing first group gives different result                                                                                       perl -ne 'print if /(line.*)(?=.*fox)/; print "$1\n"' test3.txt
line1 brown fox
line1 brown 
line1 brown 
line1 brown                                                                                                     Now (line.*) is NOT treating the entire line as one whole string. How is changing the second group (+ve lookahead vs -ve lookahead) affecting the first group (line.*) match?

Comment: The `.` does not span across line breaks by default. Using Positive Lookahead `(?=...)` only matches the first line because it has the word **fox** in it.